# Email Fails to send with sms details

Tags: email, blackberry, sms

The following code listens for an incoming sms, takes all the spaces out of the sms then emails the edited sms. Everything works fine, except that the app fails to send an email. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and help me?

```java
new Thread() { 
    public void run() {

        try {

            DatagramConnection _dc =
                (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://"); 

            for(;;) { //'For-Loop' used to listen continously for incoming sms's

                Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());                     
                _dc.receive(d);  //The sms is received                           
                byte[] bytes = d.getData();
                String address = d.getAddress(); //The address of the sms is put on a string.
                String msg = new String(bytes); //The body of the sms is put on a string.
                String msg2 = (replaceAll(msg, " ",""))  ; //


                Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();

                Folder[] folders = store.list(Folder.SENT); 
                Folder sentfolder = folders[0]; //Retrieve the sent folder 

                Message in = new Message(sentfolder); 
                Address recipients[] = new Address[1];  

                recipients[0]= new Address("me@yahoo.com", "user"); 

                in.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients); 

                in.setSubject("Incoming SMS"); //The subject of the message is added
                in.setContent("You have just received an SMS from: " + address + "/n" + "Message: " + msg2); //Here the body of the message is formed

                in.setPriority(Message.Priority.HIGH); //The priority of the message is set.

                Transport.send(in); //The message is sent

                in.setFlag(Message.Flag.OPENED, true);
                Folder folder = in.getFolder(); //The message is deleted from the sent folder
                folder.deleteMessage(in); 
            }       

        }catch (Exception me) { //All Exceptions are caught       
        }    
    }
};

public static String replaceAll(String front, String pattern, String back) {

    if (front == null) 
    return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); //A StringBufffer is created
    int idx = -1;
    int patIdx = 0;

    while ((idx = front.indexOf(pattern, patIdx)) != -1) {
        sb.append(front.substring(patIdx, idx));
        sb.append(back);
        patIdx = idx + pattern.length();
    }

    sb.append(front.substring(patIdx));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Fails to send an email" - what goes wrong? What are the symptoms? Is there an exception you're eating? Have you tried debugging? =)

Comment: There are no exceptions, the app builds and compiles just fine and opens perfectly. Funnily enough the app does send an email with the conents of the sms when I leave 'String msg2 = (replaceAll(msg, " ",""))' out and change the content of the email to msg instead of msg2, but I want the code to email the edited sms without spaces.

Comment: are you on a device with a network connection, or a simulator ... ?

Comment: and how do you know that there's no exceptions?  you have a catch block that catches everything, but does nothing (doesn't even print out a message).  are you sure there aren't exceptions being thrown that you just don't notice?

Comment: How can there be exceptions thrown when I'm catching all the exceptions? And why would the app send an email if I leave 'String msg2 = (replaceAll(msg, " ",""))' out and not send an email when I include it.

Comment: Because what you care about is code **inside** your try/catch block running into errors, and throwing exceptions.  The way that try/catch block works, it catches everything, **and then silently continues**.  This is usually not helpful for debugging.  By the way, you need to put my name with an "@" symbol in front of it in comments for me to get notified that you're responding (but I don't need to do that for you, because my comments are attached to your question).  Thanks.

Comment: ... by the way, since you're relatively new to Stack Overflow (not a bad thing at all!), you should make sure to accept, and up vote answers (or comments) that help you.  The community provides help for free, and that's the way to both say "thank you", and also mark questions as solved, so that others don't keep reading your questions, thinking that you still need help.  You have several unaccepted questions outstanding.

Comment: @Nate Can you please provide me some code on how to write my try/catch block. I can't see what is wrong with my code and its driving me crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to the problem, just an elaboration on my comment above, that might help.

Make sure do something in your exception catch block, so that problems in the code don't go unnoticed.  It's possible that your code is not encountering any exceptions, but in order for us to help, we need to try to eliminate potential problems, and since you say the code isn't working, but you have an empty exception handler, that's an easy area to fix first.

the simplest handler is just:

```java
try {
   // try sending sms here
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you can run this in the debugger (which I highly suggest), then you can now put a breakpoint on the `e.printStackTrace()` line, and see if it ever gets hit.  If it does, inspect the value of `e` and tell us what it is.

Normally, in my programs, I don't actually use `e.printStackTrace()` in catch handlers, but I have a logging class that takes strings, and maybe a log level (e.g. info, warning, error, verbose), and writes to a log file.  The log file can be attached to emails the users send to tech support, or can be disabled for production if you only want to use the feature while developing.

Anyway, start with a simple `printStackTrace()` and see if it ever gets hit.  Then, report back.

---

**Edit:** from the symptoms you describe in the comments after your question, it seems like it's a possibility that

```java
 String msg2 = (replaceAll(msg, " ",""))  ; //
```

is throwing an exception, and therefore never letting you get to where you'd send the email.  I can't see anything wrong with your implementation of `replaceAll()` upon initial inspection, but that might be a place to look.  Has that implementation been thoroughly unit-tested?

Also, I think you have a `"/n"` in your code where you probably want a `"\n"`, right?